# SQL error unable to copy file

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'v built a program, and I used SQL. It worked fine but suddenly, without changing the code, I got the error message:

> Error 3 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Programm\Programm\App_Data\DataBase_log.ldf" to
>   "bin\Debug\App_Data\DataBase_log.ldf". The process cannot access the
>   file 'C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Programm\Programm\App_Data\DataBase_log.ldf' because it
>   is being used by another process.

This is my connection string:

```
private string ConnectionString()
{
    return @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\DataBase.mdf;Initial Catalog=DataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
}
```

I'm using SQL server 2008 and Visual studio 2010.
I can't figure out what the problem is and I'd appreciate anyone who helps.

Answer (score 3):

1) Sometimes the vslshost.exe gets stuck from prior run and you can't build again as it has files open. Sometime another build works, other times you have to close VS and reopen. Other times you have go delete the process.

2) If DB will be on end user machine, then ".\SqlExpress" should work

Comment: Nothing worked, I even restarted my computer but it still shows me the error.

Comment: I think resolved this now by using a new database that you created in MS SQL Server Management Studio then added it to the VS2010 C# Project as an Existing item, rather than a new item, and it works just fine .Sometimes something have not real reason.perhaps your problem is in this category.